# Is there a way to spawn nodes uniformly?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a game where circles are moving up and down lines like so:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zKS4.png

, and Im using a .plist file to generate them, but its a little monotonous.Is there another way to generate several columns of circles uniformly without using a .plist file? Will post code if necessary.

Comment: uniformly? You mean uniformly distributed random?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a function like this:

```
func createCirclesOnLine(line : CGFloat){
    //Set this to however low you want the circles to start.
    var currentY : CGFloat = -20.0

    //Set this to however high you want the circles to go
    let maxY = self.size.height + 100

    //Set this to the spacing you want between the circles
    let spacing : CGFloat = 50

    while currentY < maxY {
        let circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 20)
        circle.position = CGPoint(x: line, y: currentY)
        self.addChild(circle)
        currentY += spacing
    }
}
```

And then pass it the line (think longitude) of wherever you want the circles to be drawn:

```
let line = self.size.width / 2
createCirclesOnLine(line)
```

Is that what you're looking for?

**EDIT: To answer your question about how to use this multiple times:**

If you want multiple lines of circles on the screen, you can simply decide what lines (again, think longitude) you want to place the circles on.  For instance, if I wanted three equally spaced lines of circles on the screen, I would do the following:

```
let line = self.size.width / 4
createCirclesOnLine(line)
createCirclesOnLine(line * 2)
createCirclesOnLine(line * 3)
```

If you try this and don't see all of the lines, you might need to add this

```
scene.size = skView.bounds.size
```

to the viewDidLoad method in your ViewController.swift right under

```
skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
```

since you are running the app in portrait mode.

Comment: Yes! thank you. How would I call this multiple times?

Comment: How you want to call it is up to you.  You could divide the screen width by 4 `let oneFourth = self.size.width / 4` and then call `createCirclesOnLine` three times.  The first time you would call it by passing it `oneFourth`, then `oneFourth * 2`, then `oneFourth * 3`.

Comment: Can you give me a clearer example? This doesn't make sense to me

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused by what you mean by "call it multiple times".  Are you wanting to use the method to place the circles at the beginning of your game? (My example in my previous comment shows how to do that) Are you wanting to use the method and call it periodically throughout the game to keep a steady flow of circles?  The method would need to change a bit to do that.

Comment: I have a few hundred lines that all have circles on them running up and down. My question is how would I take that one line of circles  and make it into a bunch of other lines of circles to place elsewhere? (populating it)

Comment: I edited my original answer.  Does that help to clarify it a bit?

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much! Im sorry but I need one more thing, is it possible to generate the circles with random spacing between them so that they're not perfectly spaced out? (y axis)

Comment: Oh sure!  Instead of using the spacing variable I made, you could just do `currentY += CGFloat((random() % 50) + 30)` or something similar.  That just gives back a random value between 30 and 79.  You'll probably have to play with the spacing.

Comment: Thank you so much haha. You're a life saver.

Comment: One more thing when you get a chance, @Trent Sartain, how can I make more circles appear on the line as the circles move up? Its only giving me like six per line.